# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error while using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, callable

I tried to plot a graph using pyplot from matplotlib and everything went fine until I tried to add the title.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a = [1, 4, 8]
b = [1, 9, 18]
plt.plot(a, b)
plt.title("Title")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

The code works fine except the title, from which an error is displayed as follows:

```
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-a1c519e5c0a1> in <module>
          4 plt.xlabel("X")
          5 plt.ylabel("Y")
    ----> 6 plt.title("title")
          7 plt.show()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

BTW, I am running this using Jupyter notebook

Comment: what is `c` in plot.show(c)? I guess you don't need it. Just use plot.show()

Comment: The code in the stack trace doesn't match the code you've given.

Comment: This code ran perfect in my Jupyter notebook... python3

Answer (score 4):

I had this error twice on the Jupyter notebook. Restart your anaconda or better: from the kernel tab restart and run all. This should work

Answer (score 2):

Restart your kernel. It’s a common error.